# Cannot instantiate GoogleHadoopFileSystem in pyspark even when JAR files are present

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

The same code is working completely fine on Linux Ubuntu with the same jar files.My spark is 3.1.2 and hadoop is 3.2. Ive tried every gcs connector version from maven.

```
val = df.write.format('bigquery') \       #df is a spark.dataframe
            .mode(mode) \
            .option("credentialsFile", "creds.json") \
            .option('table', table) \
            .option("temporaryGcsBucket", bucket) \
            .save()
```

```
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/09/17 07:41:50 WARN FileSystem: Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem could not be instantiated
21/09/17 07:41:50 WARN FileSystem: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V
21/09/17 07:41:50 WARN FileSystem: Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem could not be instantiated
21/09/17 07:41:50 WARN FileSystem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\sparktest\main.py", line 158, in <module>
    val = df.write.format('bigquery') \
  File "c:\sparktest\vnenv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 828, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "c:\sparktest\vnenv\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "c:\sparktest\vnenv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "c:\sparktest\vnenv\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o50.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` ... You didn't add GCS jars to the classpath

Comment: I added them to the jar folder in spark_home location. I will try this also if you have the proper jar version command it would help me alot. Thanks for the help @OneCricketeer

Comment: I'm not really sure about specific versions, but you can use `--packages` during spark-submit to include the necessary libraries rather than add to spark_home (which would only work on that one machine, not in a cluster)

Comment: Ive added them to the class path using spark-submit --packages. It is still giving me the same error and i opened the jar file to look for the class it is still there. This is the jar gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.1.jar @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old jars in spark jars folders weren't instantiated properly. I had to delete them and add new ones from the maven repo. Below is the code I used.

```
 spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName(appName) \
        .config(conf=spark_conf) \
        .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.22.0') \
        .getOrCreate()
```